# Python Unicode, Pyramid, UTF-8 MySQL Table issue

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I have a Python 2 Pyramid web app using SQLAlchemy to talk to a MySQL table, of which all string columns are **UTF-8** encoded. When I pull the data to display, I must use `.decode("UTF-8")` in order for it to show, otherwise I get the natural error of ASCII can not decode.

I have two questions:

1. Is there any other way of working to avoid the need of `.decode("UTF-8")` each and every time?
2. If I want to push something into the database, and I have a string which is `s = u'str'`, do I need to do anything to it when it's to be insterted to a UTF-8 column?

Thank you very much.

> For people who might find this message through a google search:
>   If you encounter an error, sort of:
>
> > **UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte in**
>
> Do use **`.encode(..)`**

Comment: Are you connecting to the database with an encoding set? For example  `create_engine('mysql+mysqldb:///mydb?charset=utf8')`.

Comment: Yes, indeed I do. "?charset=utf8&use_unicode=1"

Comment: Hello Martijn. Your comment gave me an idea. I switched use_unicode from 1 to 0 and then went onto SQLAclhemy's Unidoe instead of String column. Now it works. Do you think this is the right way?

Comment: Using `charset=` sets `use_unicode` to 1 by default. I believe SQLAlchemy can work just fine with `use_unicode` set to 1 or 0; you shoud be using the Unicode type instead of String and leave that flag alone.

Comment: Martijn, that's the problem I had. Set to 1, it did not work. Set to 0, suddenly worked and I have no idea why. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SQLAlchemy columns are of the [Unicode](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/types.html?highlight=unicode#sqlalchemy.types.Unicode) type instead of [String](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/types.html?highlight=unicode#sqlalchemy.types.String), SQLAlchemy will do the character encoding/decoding (in your case to/from `UTF-8`) for you.

Note that the [String](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/types.html?highlight=unicode#sqlalchemy.types.String) column type has a `convert_unicode` parameter which can be set to `True`, but this should only be used for the very rare cases where the database backend doesn't have native Unicode support.

As @MartijnPieters mentioned on his comment, you should be aware of the [MySQL Unicode](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=tables#unicode) section in the SQLAlchemy documentation. Namely, if you don't explicitly set the character encoding in the connection to the database with:

```
# set client encoding to utf8; all strings come back as unicode
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb:///mydb?charset=utf8')
```

(the following is mostly quoted from the *SQLAlchemy* documentation)

*"[...] many MySQL server installations default to a `latin1` encoding for client connections, which has the effect of all data being converted into `latin1`, even if you have `utf8` or another character set configured on your tables and columns. The charset parameter as received by MySQL-Python also has the side-effect of enabling `use_unicode=1`."*

*"Manually configuring `use_unicode=0` will cause MySQL-python to return encoded strings:"*

```
# set client encoding to utf8; all strings come back as utf8 str
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb:///mydb?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0')
```

Comment: Hello Pedro. I converted my Column(String(128)) to Column(Unicode(128)) however still the data obtained has type 'str' after querying the MySQL DB. What do you think might I be doing wrong?

Comment: The connection string - like Martin Pieters puts it on the comment - the utf-8 charse must be set at connection time when talking to MySQL

Comment: Can you recreate the database from the SQLAlchemy metadata? If the MySQL column is a `VARCHAR` instead of a `NVARCHAR`, I think you'll have the described behaviour.

Comment: Will try Pedro. Thank you very much for your responses and time.